# retransmissions/out-of-order packets with large (~1 MB) writes/reads w/ TCP (SOCK_STREAM) over localhost loopback -- ACK lost

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, loopback

I'm seeing retransmissions/out-of-order packets when using the loopback interface and have been googling for days to try to determine if I should be surprised by this (which I am) or if anyone else is seeing it, but I haven't found any answers.
Apologies if I'm just missing something. Someone mentioned a loopback specification, 
but I can't find it. Does anyone know of the loopback interface specification?

Example retransmission because of missing ACK:

```
/root
root@cmsstor911 :^| tshark -nr/tmp/t.tcpdump -te | egrep -i 'retrans|out.of.order' -B3 -A2 
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
 54 1582904297    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 66 7001 > 45529 [ACK] Seq=449 Ack=917399 Win=2752512 Len=0 TSval=3255514024 TSecr=3255514024
 55 1582904297    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 65549 45529 > 7001 [ACK] Seq=982882 Ack=449 Win=49152 Len=65483 TSval=3255514024 TSecr=3255514024
 56 1582904297    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 278 45529 > 7001 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1048365 Ack=449 Win=49152 Len=212 TSval=3255514024 TSecr=3255514024
 57 1582904297    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 278 [TCP Retransmission] 45529 > 7001 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1048365 Ack=449 Win=49152 Len=212 TSval=3255514034 TSecr=3255514024
 58 1582904297    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 78 7001 > 45529 [ACK] Seq=449 Ack=1048577 Win=2686976 Len=0 TSval=3255514034 TSecr=3255514024 SLE=1048365 SRE=1048577
 59 1582904297    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 178 7001 > 45529 [PSH, ACK] Seq=449 Ack=1048577 Win=2686976 Len=112 TSval=3255514224 TSecr=3255514024
```

It's hard to get tshark to print microseconds nicely, but what seems to be happening is that packet 56 is the last packet for a while (in my application). An ack occurred 2 packets prior, so one should be sent, but it isn't. Approx. 9.056 ms elapses and the sending side decides to retransmit.  The receiving side timely sends a SACK.

Here's one thing that I'm doing (tried on several modern Linux kernels, including 5.5.4):

```
sudo tcpdump -s78 -wt.tcpdump -ilo port 7001 & tcpdump_pid=$!; \
taskset -c 1 ./tcp_loopback.py -s -b1048576 & sleep .5; taskset -c 2 ./tcp_loopback.py -c -b1048576 --count=8192; \
sudo kill $tcpdump_pid; \
tshark -r t.tcpdump | egrep -i 'retrans|out.of.order' | tail
```

The tcp_loopback.py script is available at home.fnal.gov/~ron/tcp_loopback.py

The heart of the server portion (-s) is:

```
    sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
    sock.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )
    sock.bind( ('127.0.0.1', port) )
    sock.listen( 4 )
    sockconn,address = sock.accept()
    while 1:
        data = sockconn.recv(bs)
        if opargs['-v']=='': print('received: '+str(len(data)))
        if len(data) == 0:
            if opargs['-v']=='': print('0 data, closing')
            break
```

The heart of the client portion (-s) is:

```
    sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
    sock.connect( ('127.0.0.1',port) )
    for xx in range(cnt): sock.send( '*'*bs )
```

The probability of retransmission seems to increase with larger (i.e. 2M, 4M) writes/reads.

I've read (e.g. Documentation/networking/scaling.rst) about out-of-order issues related 
to scheduling on different cores, hence the use of "taskset" above.

I believe that the retransmissions are real in that I see, in the tcpdump, segments transmitted twice. Also, I have a custom application that uses a NETLINK_SOCK_DIAG socket to get the retransmissions information while a transmission is in progress; and I see retransmission with localhost/loopback while using it. It does seem that the vast majority (maybe all) of the transmissions are caused be the out-of-order phenomenon, so the question may really be: are there any tricks to play (in addition to taskset) to assure packet order while using the loopback interface?

With loopback, don't really know if I'm looking at the send processing sending things out-of-order or the receive processing receiving things out-of-order. My ultimate goal is to establish a baseline for low-latency inter-node transmission in a 100 Gi, high congestion 
(many-to-one) environment. I developed an application that uses the "debug socket" to get retransmission information and I was surprised to see retransmissions on localhost.

Can anyone please help me understand what's happening and if there are any knobs (e.g. sysctl) to turn to eliminate retransmission while still maximizing data rate?

Thanks,
Ron

P.S. I also eventually see the issue when I do this:

```
while true;do
 sudo tcpdump -s78 -w/tmp/t.tcpdump -ilo port 7001 & tcpdump_pid=$!
 ncat -4l localhost 7001 > /dev/null & ncat_pid=$!
 sleep .5
 dd if=/dev/zero bs=1048576 count=2048 | ncat localhost 7001
 sudo kill $tcpdump_pid
 tshark -r /tmp/t.tcpdump | egrep -i 'retrans|out.of.order' && break
done
```

Example output:

```
/home/ron/notes
ron@ronlap77 :^) sudo tcpdump -s78 -wt.tcpdump -ilo port 7001 & tcpdump_pid=$!; \
> taskset -c 1 ./tcp_loopback.py -s -b1048576 & sleep .5; taskset -c 2 ./tcp_loopback.py -c -b1048576 --count=8192; \
> sudo kill $tcpdump_pid; \
> tshark -r t.tcpdump | egrep -i 'retrans|out.of.order' | tail
[1] 29066
[2] 29067
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 78 bytes
191379 packets captured
383230 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
[2]+  Done                    taskset -c 1 ./tcp_loopback.py -s -b1048576
189947   1.092534    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 65549 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 46988 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=4203412074 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=65483 TSval=2693245609 TSecr=2693245609
189948   1.092535    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 65549 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 46988 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=4203477557 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=65483 TSval=2693245609 TSecr=2693245609
189949   1.092536    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 65549 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 46988 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=4203543040 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=65483 TSval=2693245609 TSecr=2693245609
189950   1.092536    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 65549 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 46988 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=4203608523 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=65483 TSval=2693245609 TSecr=2693245609
189951   1.092537    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 65549 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 46988 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=4203674006 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=65483 TSval=2693245609 TSecr=2693245609
189962   1.092594    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 65549 [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 46988 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=4203674006 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=65483 TSval=2693245609 TSecr=2693245609
190115   1.093456    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 65549 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 46988 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=4211997131 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=65483 TSval=2693245610 TSecr=2693245610
190116   1.093457    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 65549 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 46988 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=4212062614 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=65483 TSval=2693245610 TSecr=2693245610
190117   1.093457    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 1762 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 46988 → 7001 [PSH, ACK] Seq=4212128097 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=1696 TSval=2693245610 TSecr=2693245610
190138   1.093547    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 1762 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 46988 → 7001 [PSH, ACK] Seq=4212128097 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=1696 TSval=2693245610 TSecr=2693245610
[1]+  Done                    sudo tcpdump -s78 -wt.tcpdump -ilo port 7001
--2020-02-25_11:27:17--
```

Comment: Hey @R.Rex - have you tried turning off "offloading features"? Not sure it makes a difference but possibly worth a short: ethtool -k lo gro off gso off tso off